# ERROR: Symbol file could not be found. windbg.exe

Tags: debugging, windbg, symbols, w3wp

I downloaded the symbols from http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/symbolpkg.mspx
the package (Windows 7 RTM x86 retail symbols, all languages) but it still gives me the same error!

Done .sympath but still not working

.sympath C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ProductsService\bin\ProductsEntityModel.pdb;srv*c:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.12.0002.633 X86
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.12.0002.633 X86
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

CommandLine: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe -ap "DefaultAppPool" -v "v4.0" -l "webengine4.dll" -a \\.\pipe\iisipm6cb8674b-5fd5-4b1c-aac4-cd0d8af98602 -h "C:\inetpub\temp\apppools\DefaultAppPool.config" -w "" -m 0 -t 20
Symbol search path is: *** Invalid ***
****************************************************************************
* Symbol loading may be unreliable without a symbol search path.           *
* Use .symfix to have the debugger choose a symbol path.                   *
* After setting your symbol path, use .reload to refresh symbol locations. *
****************************************************************************
Executable search path is: 
ModLoad: 00a90000 00a98000   w3wp.exe
ModLoad: 77490000 775cc000   ntdll.dll
ModLoad: 75990000 75a64000   C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
ModLoad: 75760000 757aa000   C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
ModLoad: 76ee0000 76f80000   C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
ModLoad: 77080000 7712c000   C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
ModLoad: 75ea0000 75eb9000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
ModLoad: 76c80000 76d21000   C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
ModLoad: 74b90000 74b9b000   C:\Windows\system32\pcwum.DLL
ModLoad: 775f0000 776b9000   C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
ModLoad: 77030000 7707e000   C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
ModLoad: 758f0000 758fa000   C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
ModLoad: 76f90000 7702d000   C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
ModLoad: 77330000 7748c000   C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
ModLoad: 712c0000 712f6000   c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\IISUTIL.dll
ModLoad: 77240000 7725f000   C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
ModLoad: 77260000 7732c000   C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
ModLoad: 75540000 7554c000   C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
ModLoad: 748c0000 748e1000   C:\Windows\system32\ntmarta.dll
ModLoad: 75ec0000 75f05000   C:\Windows\system32\WLDAP32.dll
ModLoad: 723d0000 723e0000   c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wphost.dll
ModLoad: 76d30000 76dbf000   C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
ModLoad: 710f0000 7114b000   c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\nativerd.dll
ModLoad: 757b0000 758cc000   C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
ModLoad: 75630000 7563c000   C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
ModLoad: 756d0000 756ff000   C:\Windows\system32\XmlLite.dll
ModLoad: 715f0000 715f9000   C:\Windows\system32\ktmw32.dll
ModLoad: 70e30000 70e67000   c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\IISRES.DLL
ModLoad: 75070000 75086000   C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
ModLoad: 74e10000 74e4b000   C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
ModLoad: 70110000 7015a000   C:\Windows\system32\mscoree.dll
ModLoad: 754f0000 7553b000   C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
ModLoad: 75900000 75983000   C:\Windows\system32\CLBCatQ.DLL
ModLoad: 70d80000 70dae000   C:\Windows\system32\mlang.dll
ModLoad: 700a0000 70106000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll
ModLoad: 76b60000 76bb7000   C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
eax=00000000 ebx=fffffffe ecx=739b4a50 edx=00000020 esi=77567380 edi=77567340
eip=774d64f4 esp=0013f9fc ebp=0013fa18 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for ntdll.dll - 
ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet:
774d64f4 c3              ret
PINCHY\JB Hi Fi (npipe w3wp) connected at Fri Jan 28 15:08:38 2011
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll -
```

Am I missing something? 
Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would have the sympath like this

```
.sympath srv*c:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ProductsService\bin
```

You could probably have mismatched symbols. Here is a command which will help in diagnosing the symbol load problems `!sym noisy`

Comment: hey! thanks for the respond. Now It says "mismatched pdb" what does that mean? 
DBGHELP: c:\symbols\ntdll.pdb\8F28FABF69C045F193E62056E642DF5C2\ntdll.pdb - mismatched pdb Have I got the wrong version?

Comment: Yes you have mismatched symbols. The easiest option is to delete the symbols that you have manually downloaded and let the tool download the correct version. I would also run something like this symchk -r C:\windows\System32\*.dll . Here is good post by John Robbins on symbols http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2010/06/02/the-secret-to-avoiding-debugger-slowdowns.aspx .

Comment: Thanks Naveen! The tool cannot download the symbols. That's why I have downloaded the symbols manually. I just couldn't get it downloaded, i don't know why. Thanks for the blog I will check it out.